# Dynamically add and filter images in Jekyll for github pages?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I am trying out Jekyll to help someone who's not all that technical maintain their own static site. I would like to be able to have a images directory in the app's root `/images` containing images following a naming convention:

```
post_one_1.jpg, post_one_2.jpg, post_two_1.jpg, post_two_2.jpg ... etc.
```

I would then like for the user to create a post (post_one) and dynamically grab all of the images pertaining to that post from the images directory.

This plugin (https://gist.github.com/jgatjens/8925165) does almost exactly what I need, but isn't compatible with github pages.

Is there a solution in which I can hand the site off to a user and they would only need to add images to the image directory following the naming convention and then create a post and have access to the images?

Comment: how about use a while loop to retrieve these images via ajax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you have a post file **_posts/2015-05-28-post_one.md**

From inside this post you have :

- page.id  = /2015/05/29/post_one
- page.dir = /2015/05/29

In order to extract **post_one** whe do :

```
{% assign imgNameStart = page.id | remove: page.dir | remove: "/" %}
```

We now generate the base path we search for :

```
{% assign imgBasePath = imgNameStart | prepend: "/images/" %}
```

in this case it will be **imgBasePath = "/images/post_one"**

Loop over all our static files (files that are not pages or posts).

```
{% for img in site.static_files %}
```

And print images that have **/images/post_one** in their path like **/images/post_one-01.jpg** or **/images/post_one-wathever-you-want.jpg**

```
{% if img.path contains imgBasePath %}
<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ img.path }}">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

All together :

```
{% assign imgNameStart = page.id | remove: page.dir | remove: "/" %}
{% assign imgBasePath = imgNameStart | prepend: "/images/" %}
{% for img in site.static_files %}
{% if img.path contains imgBasePath %}
<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ img.path }}">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Beware of code indentation if your post is a markdown file, four space indentation can be transformed to code snippet.